# JQuery Adding the values of 2 divs into a third div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 divs with numbers in each...

```
<div id="one">1</div>

<div id="two">5</div>

<div id="total">0</div>
```

What I need to do for example is:

If #one is click then Add the values of #one and #two and update it on #total

So, in the case above total would look like this:

```
<div id="total">6</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#one').click(function(){
$("#total").text(
    parseFloat($(this).text()) + 
    parseFloat($("#two").text())
);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<div id="one">1</div>

<div id="two">5</div>

<div id="total">0</div>

<input id="btn-calculate" type="button" value="Calculate" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var one = document.getElementById('one'),
    two = document.getElementById('two'),
    total = document.getElementById('total');
document.getElementById('btn-calculate').onclick = function() {
    total.innerHTML = parseInt(one.innerHTML) + parseInt(two.innerHTML);
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/3fB3R/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/jjVBW/1/)**

```
$("#one").click(function() {
   $('#total').text(parseFloat($('#one').text()) + parseFloat($('#two').text()));
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

```
​$("#one")​.click(function(){
    $("#total").html(parseInt($(this).text()) + parseInt($("#two").text()))
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daniilr/G4Snm/

Comment: Always specify the `radix` to guarantee predictable result. `parseInt($(this).text(), 10)`