# Calculate sum of two different HTML elements and show in third div with Jquery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two different HTML elements and i want to calculate the sum and display the value in third div.

I have a select box with 3 option values and a div with fixed value. I want the sum to be calculated based on the option selected in dropdown.

I have tried to research and fount this. But i have dropdown in my case and total needs to change: [JQuery Adding the values of 2 divs into a third div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972541/jquery-adding-the-values-of-2-divs-into-a-third-div)

Here is the code below:

```html
<select>
  <option value ="1100"> $1100 </option>
  <option value ="1200"> $1200 </option>
  <option value ="1300"> $1300 </option>
</select>

<div id="shipping">$4.99</div>

<div id ="total"></div>
```

I need to show the total amount in `total` div and change as the option change in dropdown.

First the default sum will be with the first value `+ $4.99`. I am new to jQuery, so couldn't make it work.

Comment: Do you need this to be a multi-select? I.e. total up the choices or just add 4.99 to the current selection?

Comment: Just go for it! [What did you try?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa Jusr add 4.99 to current selection

Comment: @MaorRefaeli It can be done through Javascript and jquery and i am not really good at it. Why would i post a question if i already know the answer. Kindly understand the problem first before voting to close down the question.

Comment: In that case jQuery already have an example of that on their docs: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: @SahibjotSingh Maor isn't wrong here, you do need to make some attempt first. Stack Overflow is not a free coding service, you are expected to put in as much work as possible to resolve the problem yourself before asking.

Comment: @SahibjotSingh StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. You are expected to research and make an attempt on your own, and if you get stuck on a particular aspect you can post your existing code and tell us what the problem is, then we can help with that.

Comment: @Alexander De Sousa Amen!

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa i just updated my question with the code i have been trying to execute. But it didn't work. Sorry that i didn't add it earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the number part from shipping element by using `substr()`. Then add that to the selected value. Try the following way:

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  var s = $('#shipping').text().substr(1);
  $('#total').text('$'+(Number(s)+Number($(this).val())));
});
$('select').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value ="1100"> $1100 </option>
  <option value ="1200"> $1200 </option>
  <option value ="1300"> $1300 </option>
</select>

<div id="shipping">$4.99</div>

<div id ="total"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this code. I have been trying to make it work from last 8 hours. It works really great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example you can use:

```js
function select_changed(value) {
var shipping = parseInt(document.getElementById("shipping").innerHTML.substring(1));
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = '$' + (shipping + parseInt(value));
}
```

```html
<select id="price" onchange="select_changed(value)">
<option value =""> </option>
<option value ="1100"> $1100 </option>
<option value ="1200"> $1200 </option>
<option value ="1300"> $1300 </option>
</select>

<div id="shipping">$4.99</div>

<div id ="total"></div>
```

Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

What about with vanilla js without using **unnecessary** third party libraries for this kinda simple task?

```js
function mySelection(selTag) {
  var selected = Number(selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));
  var default_val = Number(document.getElementById('shipping').innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));
  var total = selected + default_val;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = `$${total}`; 
}
```

```html
<select  onchange="mySelection(this)">
<option value ="1100"> $1100 </option>
<option value ="1200"> $1200 </option>
<option value ="1300"> $1300 </option>
</select>

<div id="shipping">$4.99</div>

<div id ="total"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this code and it works really well. But i chose the other one as the best answer because i can't call a function through select. I really appreciate your time and have upvoted your answer as this could be the solution someone may search for.

Comment: @SahibjotSingh You're welcome, No prob. Best of luck mate :)